# How to fix firebase otp verification and sms permissions in android app?

Tags: android, firebase, permissions, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on an app that uses firebase otp authentication system. As you all know Google has updated their privacy policy restricting developers from adding sms and call log permissions. Since I'm using read_sms and receive_sms permissions in my app, google is denying my request for upload. I tried removing these permissions and uploading it, which was successful but then realized that my app wasn't receiving the otp message after removing read_sms and receive_sms permissions from my app after uploading to the play store. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see how to write effective questions in stackoverflow. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: can you specify which permission you added ? for sms sending and receiving

Comment: @SarthakJoshi I'm not asking anyone to write any code, I'm asking as to how should I go about handling this.

Comment: @CoderMal "READ_SMS" and "RECEIVE_SMS"